# shinyloadtest record on mac doesnt stop when closing browser

Tags: macos, shiny, rstudio

I've installed the shinyloadtest package and shinycannon on my mac (MacOS Sierra).  When I start a recording session either in a terminal or in the console of RStudio the session doesn't stop when I close the tab or the browser.  I've tried both Chrome and Safari.  I can kill the session but then I cannot use the recording.log file to run a load test.  I get an error:

Uncaught exception on thread00
java.lang.IllegalStateException: last event in log not a WS_CLOSE (did you close the tab after recording?)
    at com.rstudio.shinycannon.EnduranceTest.run(Main.kt:280)

Well, I did close the tab but the recording session did not stop.

Has anyone else encountered this on a mac?  Any ideas on what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what was wrong but I removed the shinyloadtest package and reinstalled it and now it is working as expected.